# Input, Edit action in Form Input Data Access 2013

Tags: ms-access

I am writing vba for my work at Banking to manage my data in Access 2013, but i have something wrong when i try to run my code.
[File DB here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RbejiRmSbPMfxmbjS-Mg6wwHBRMxJuQY/view?usp=sharing)

[image: OS]

My code which i used to find out in internet is:

```
Private Sub cmdthem_Click()        
    If Me.TXTLCNO.Tag & "" = "" Then
        CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO db(NOLCTRANSACTION, LCTYPE, LCXKLCNKREF, BENAPPLICANT, AMOUNT, CONTRACTNO, INPUTTER, AUTHORIZER, DATE, STATUS, NOTE) " & _
        " VALUES(" & Me.TXTLCNO & ",'" & Me.CBO1 & "','" & _
        Me.TXTREF & "','" & Me.TXTBEN & "#,'" & Me.TXTAMOUNT & "',#" & _
        Me.TXTCONTRACT & "','" & Me.CBO2 & "','" & Me.CBO3 & "#,'" & Me.TXTDATE & "',#" & _
        Me.TXTSTATUS & "','" & Me.TXTNOTE & "')"
    Else
        'otherwise (Tag of txtID store the id of db to modified)
        'CurrentDb.Execute "Update db " & _
        " SET NOLCTRANSACTION=" & Me.TXTLCNO & _
        ", LCTYPE='" & Me.CBO1 & "'" & _
        ", LCXKLCNKREF='" & Me.TXTREF & "'" & _
        ", BENAPPICANT='" & Me.TXTBEN & "'" & _
        ", AMOUNT='" & Me.TXTAMOUNT & "'" & _
        ", CONTRACTNO='" & Me.TXTCONTRACT & "'" & _
        ", INPUTTER='" & Me.CBO2 & "'" & _
        ", AUTHORIZER='" & Me.CBO3 & "'" & _
        ", DATE='" & Me.TXTDATE & "'" & _
        ", STATUS='" & Me.TXTSTATUS & "'" & _
        ", NOTE='" & Me.TXTNOTE & "'" & _
        " WHERE NOLCTRANSACTION=" & Me.NOLC.Tag
    End If
    'clear form
    cmdclear_Click
    'refresh data in list
    db_subform.Form.Requery
End Sub
```

But when i try to run this command, it always errors statement INSERT INTO db

My table's name is db, it has all fields above

Can you find out my mistake please? Thank you, best regards

Comment: You have two # parameter characters that should be apostrophes - the first one and the last one. If any field is a number type (Amount ?), do not use any delimiters.

Comment: i try to do but it doesn't work. Can you help me to debug my code

CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO (NOLC, LCTYPE, LCXKLCNKREF, BENAPPLICANT, AMOUNT, CONTRACTNO, INPUTTER, AUTHORIZER, DATE, STATUS, NOTE) " & _
" VALUES(" & Me.TXTLCNO & ",'" & Me.CBO1 & "','" & _
Me.TXTREF & "','" & Me.TXTBEN & "','" & Me.TXTAMOUNT & "','" & _
Me.TXTCONTRACT & "','" & Me.CBO2 & "','" & Me.CBO3 & "','" & _
Me.TXTDATE & "','" & Me.TXTSTATUS & "','" & Me.NOTE & "')"

Comment: I said to replace 2 # not all 4. You have one date field so you need 1 pair of # delimiters: `"',#" & _ Me.TXTDATE & "#,'"`. And if Amount is a number type field, remove apostrophes: `"'," & Me.TXTAMOUNT & ",'"`

Comment: CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO db(NOLC, LCTYPE, LCXKLCNKREF, BENAPPLICANT, AMOUNT, CONTRACTNO, INPUTTER, AUTHORIZER, DATE, STATUS, NOTE) " & _
" VALUES(" & Me.TXTLCNO & ",'" & Me.CBO1 & "','" & _
Me.TXTREF & "','" & Me.TXTBEN & "'," & Me.TXTAMOUNT & ",'" & _
Me.TXTCONTRACT & "','" & Me.CBO2 & "','" & Me.CBO3 & "',#" & _
Me.TXTDATE & "#,'" & Me.TXTSTATUS & "','" & Me.NOTE & "')"

Iam looking forward hearing from you, is that right?

Comment: Looks good. Try it and find out. If you still have issue, edit your question with revised attempt and new info.

Comment: Thanks for  your advise. I used this code for my vba but it still doesn't work. it notices Error INSERT INTO.... Please help me to resolve this code. Thanks

Comment: You have not edited the question with revised code and entire error message. The syntax I gave you is appropriate.

Comment: If NOLC is text type field then you also need apostrophe delimiters for the data parameter.

Comment: My require was updated. Please help me to resolve it. Thanks

Comment: Field name is NOLC, not NOLCTRANSACTION. This is a text type field which means you need apostrophe delimiters for the input: `" VALUES('" & Me.TXTLCNO & "','" & `. You do not have the # delimiters correct. See earlier comment. Number fields DO NOT use delimiters.

Comment: Looked at cmdclear code. References control named LCNO, it should be TXTLCNO. Why are you setting Tag property to empty string? I doubt this should be done.

Comment: Why are you using code to save data? Why not bind controls to fields? Then data entered will pass directly to table. When you want to enter new record just go to New Record row, no VBA needed. Have you looked at the intrinsic Split form?

Comment: @June7 if i bind controls to fields, can i edit data directly ? I want to lock my table record. When i want to edit record, i must click on table record and click in button ?

Comment: @June7 when in bind controls to fields, my sub form won't requery. Can you show me how to requery the sub form ?

Comment: Yes, bound controls allow editing data directly. I don't understand 'locking' record. If user can just click a button to make record editable why bother locking? Really should look at intrinsic Split form. You are attempting to emulate it. I downloaded db and I have fixed every syntax error I can find in your code and it still errors. Annoying.

Comment: I rebuilt the SQL statement and tested 1 field at a time. It errors on the DATE and NOTE fields. Enclose DATE in [ ] like `[DATE]`. Date is a reserved word. Should not use reserved words as names for anything. Do the same for NOTE. I did not know it was a reserved word. If you bind fields, try code in main form AfterUpdate event to requery subform.

Comment: @June7 Can you share me your fixed code every syntax via email? My email is nguyenhaminhedu@gmail.com. Thanks for your fixing

Comment: No email. Here is the SQL: `CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO db(NOLC, LCTYPE, LCXKLCNKREF, BENAPPLICANT, AMOUNT, CONTRACTNO, INPUTTER, AUTHORIZER, [DATE], STATUS, [NOTE]) " & _
"VALUES('" & Me.TXTLCNO & "','" & Me.CBO1 & "','" & Me.TXTREF & "','" & Me.TXTBEN & "'," & Me.TXTAMOUNT & ",'" & Me.TXTCONTRACT & "','" & _
Me.CBO2 & "','" & Me.CBO3 & "',#" & Me.TXTDATE & "#,'" & Me.TXTSTATUS & "','" & Me.TXTNOTE & "')"`